# How to terminate a POST web service call - ORDS

Tags: oracle, rest, web-services, terminate

Please excuse my ignorance as I am a total beginner.

I have created a basic RESTful Web Services Using PL/SQL, sample code below(which works perfectly fine)

```
 ords.define_template(
      p_module_name => 'restDemo',
      p_pattern => 'updateClient');
  ords.define_handler(
      p_module_name => 'restDemo',
      p_pattern => 'updateClient',
      p_method  => 'POST',
      p_source_type => ords.source_type_plsql,
      p_source => 'declare 
                      w_clob clob := :body_text; 
                   begin 
                      ws.ws_interface.update_client(w_clob); 
                   exception 
                      when others then 
                         package.ws_interface.g_result_rec.result_message := SQLERRM;  
                   end;');
```

When `ws_interface.update_client` is initiated via the post request, in the initialization of `ws_interface` package, I am calling a routine thats determines if the client can be updated or not (based on access of the user logged in to the DB).

If the user does not have access to execute the `updateClient` service - I want to terminate the service call, which I have no idea on how to go about do this.

**So my question is:**

How do I go about terminating the current active `updateClient` webservice call ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `ws_interface` package, if the client can not be updated, then you just need to `return` so that the PL/SQL block in the POST definition will complete. Your code can look something like this:

```sql
---Beginning of package
...
procedure update_client (some_clob clob) is
begin
  --The client can not be updated so do no more processing.
  if can_update_client = false then
    --Some sort of error message could also be added here
    return;
  end if;

  --Rest of processing for updating the client
end;
...
---End of package
```